# Base64.encode(bytearray, Base64.DEFAULT) result of this method will add 10 at last item

Tags: java, android

When i encode my byte array using Base64.encode(bytearray, Base64.DEFAULT) so result of this method will add 10 at last item in the resulting byte array and when i converting this resulting byte array into string than 10 will convert into \n(line feed) at the end 
please let me know why the \n will append at the end

below is the code that will convert the string into byte array

```
    int inLength = hexValue.length();
    int i, o = 0;
    long outByte = 0;
    byte[] outBytes = new byte[(inLength / 2)];

    for (i = 0; i < inLength; i++) {
        char c = hexValue.charAt(i);
        int value = -1;

        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            value = (c - '0');
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
            value = 10 + (c - 'A');
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
            value = 10 + (c - 'a');

        if (value >= 0) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                outBytes[o++] = (byte) ((outByte << 4) | value);
                outByte = 0;
            } else {
                outByte = value;
            }

        } else {
            if (o != 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    return outBytes;
```

Comment: How is the byte array created?

Comment: Are you sure that extra line feed was not already in there?

Comment: @hexafraction below is the code where i just pass the string into this code and this will return that byte array after that i encode this array 
  byte[] outBytes = new byte[(inLength / 2)];
  for (i = 0; i < inLength; i++) {
   char c = hexValue.charAt(i);
   int value = -1;
   if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    value = (c - '0');
   else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
    value = 10 + (c - 'A');
   else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
    value = 10 + (c - 'a');
   if (value >= 0) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
     outBytes[o++] = (byte) ((outByte << 4) | value);
     outByte = 0;
    } else {
     outByte = valu

Comment: @Thilo how to identify the extra line feed is already included ?

Comment: @KiranChoudhary Edit your post as code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: this is the string "51b034267f00000144495444" that i convert into byte  array and after that encode that byte array using Base64.encode(bytearray, Base64.DEFAULT) so in the resulting encoding array response the last element of that array is "10" and when i convert this again into string it will convert into \n please let me know where this char will come

Comment: Do a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytearray))` to see what is in there. Also writing a simple JUnit test case for this part of your code might help.

Comment: What has the posted code to do with the question? It decodes hex encoded bytes and not Base64 encoded bytes.

Comment: @Henry true but this code is posted due to someone on this thread will ask for a code

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment right now so i had to leave a reply.
Is this code written by you? or Someone else?

For Base64 encoding, byte are processed in blocks of 3 bytes at a time. If the length of the array is not a multiple of three then either one or two '0' zero bytes is appended to make full block.

And why are you writing your own logic where there are some API available to do the work for you?

Update: I just run the code again with help of API.

```
Input String: 51b034267f00000144495444
```

And

```
Corresponding Base64 encoded String: NTFiMDM0MjY3ZjAwMDAwMTQ0NDk1NDQ0
```

Simply put, 3 bytes will result in 4 plain text encoded bytes.